# How to format seconds into time without showing unnecessary zeros

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have seconds and I want to transform them like this: `0:14`, `1:25`, `1:10:45` without the leading zeros. I've already tried with `gmdate` but it has leading zeros.

Is there any way to do this using`Carbon` or I have to create custom function for that?

Updated: This is my current code:

```
Carbon::now()->subSeconds($seconds)->diffForHumans(Carbon::now(), true, true);
```

And the number of seconds is integer and could be even big `2000` or more..
It's shown as `14s`, `25m` and I want to be `0:14`, `25:27` - to show the seconds too.

Comment: So you want `:14` or `14` or what? Only one of the three examples has leading zeros

Comment: I want `0:14` but don't want `00:00:14` as it is using `gmdate`

Comment: Can you please show your current code and the starting string (e.g. `00:00:14` = start and `0:14` should be the output)?

Comment: Well, i haven't found solution to the problem. I have `$seconds = 40; // data from the database` and want to format them

Comment: How large can `$seconds` be? You are expanding it to minutes, hours, days, etc currently?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function like this:

```
public function customDiffInHuman($date1, $date2)
{
    $diff_in_humans = '';
    $diff = 0;
    if($hours = $date1->diffInHours($date2, null)){
        $diff_in_humans .= $hours;
        $diff = $hours * 60;
    }

    $minutes = $date1->diffInMinutes($date2, null);
    $aux_minutes = $minutes;
    if($hours)
        $minutes -= $diff;
    $diff = $aux_minutes * 60;

    $diff_in_humans .= ($diff_in_humans) ? ':'.str_pad($minutes, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) : $minutes;


    if($seconds = $date1->diffInSeconds($date2, null)){
        if($diff)
            $seconds -= $diff;
        $diff_in_humans .=  ':'.str_pad($seconds, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $diff_in_humans;
}
```

If you put this function in one of your classes or in a Helper and call it for example:

```
$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(14);
$date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::now();    
echo $your_class->customDiffInHuman($date1, $date2); // This will output 00:14

$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(125);
$date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::now();    
echo $your_class->customDiffInHuman($date1, $date2); // This will output 2:05

$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(3725);
$date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::now();    
echo $your_class->customDiffInHuman($date1, $date2); // This will output 1:02:05
```

Comment: I'll try it. How about using `Carbon`? I couldn't ind a way to do it with Carbon